# vb.net: Why all contained controls within a groupbox do NOT respond to Enabling/disabling?

Tags: vb.net, containers, grouping

I'm working on a winform which contains several controls like textboxes, radio buttons, datagridviews... All of these controls have been added to a main group box called gbDataEntry.

My problem is when the user is seeing the form, I set gbDataEntry.Enabled = False but I want to enable some controls like DataGridviews so the user can scroll them. After disabling gbDataGridview I set DataGridView1.Enabled = True but it seems that the datagridview does not respond to this line. Why?

Is anything wrong with it?

Comment: Standard Windows behavior, the parent window always wins.  You'll have to do this differently.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard .NET behaviour (as mentioned in the comment): if a container is disabled then all controls it contains are disabled and cannot be enabled separrately:

> When a container control has its enabled property set to false, all its contained controls are disabled, as well. For example, if the user clicks on any of the controls contained in a disabled GroupBox control, no events are raised.

[(from Control.Enabled Property on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx)

Why do you want to implement this in such a way? The messy solution to this is to enable/disable controls individually.